# requests.get doesn't care about my proxies [http / https / sock4 / sock5]

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I want to test the working state of proxies contained in a list.
Proxies can be HTTP/HTTPS or Socks4/socks5 type and they are formatted this way  :

> 104.207.147.141:8080
> 103.216.51.210:8191
> 3.9.34.151:3128
> 191.232.214.74:8080
> socks4://138.59.143.37:57669
> socks4://185.169.181.24:4145
> socks4://45.115.112.214:40308

to test them I realize a request on the site http://ifconfig.me/ip which sends me back my IP if it was reached correctly. :

```
def tester(proxies, ip, ref_IPs):
  whitelist = []

  for proxy in range(0, len(proxies), 1):
    print(proxies[proxy])
    rep = requests.get("http://ifconfig.me/ip", {'http': proxies[proxy], 'https': proxies[proxy]}, timeout=1)
    if rep.text == ip:
        whitelist.append(ref_IPs[proxy])
    fileCreator(cleaner(whitelist, 1))
```

the whole thing works well, but the proxies don't seem to have any influence on the request. Proxies are therefore all concidered as functional regardless of the address.

> 191.232.214.74:8080 -> work
> socks4://138.59.143.37:57669 -> work
> AAA.k4.yy.43:B345 -> work

can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requests.get have the following prototype:

```
requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)
```

What you need is the parameter 'proxies' in the kwargs so your request must looks like that:

```
rep = requests.get("http://ifconfig.me/ip", proxies={'http': proxies[proxy], 'https': proxies[proxy]}, timeout=1)
```